# How to handle back button if we will get browser options pop up?

Tags: android

[image]I have one link in my application, if I click on that link it will open one web page in browser. So, if we have more than one browser in our mobile,for example in my mobile I have uc browser and google chrome, so, after clicking on that link in my application it is showing one pop up to choose in which browser I want to open that link. Now my problem is I want to handle the back button of that pop up where we will get the pop up to choose our required browser. Please help me how I can  handle the same.

Comment: could you please explain clearly what do you want to do?

Comment: please go through the image I uploaded and please tell me how to handle the back button of that pop up.

Comment: @shree could you please update image url?

Comment: sorry @gokhan I dint understand. what do you mean update image url,. you want to give image as link?.

Comment: @shree I wanted to see your uploaded image

Comment: I already uploaded the image and you can see the same in my question.